# Docker - where to view full logs for service scale

Tags: docker

Fairly simple question but I can't seem to Google it. Basically I'm running the following command, and the output is being cropped:

```
$ docker service scale omni_platform_omni_gallery_db=1
omni_platform_omni_gallery_db scaled to 1
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
1/1: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /ho…
```

I need to view the full output, and I can't seem to find a /var/log/docker.log or anything of that kind.

Any help is appreciated thanks :)

EDIT:

I tried the following too, to no avail:

```
$ docker service ps omni_platform_omni_gallery_db --format {{.Error}}
"invalid mount config for type…"
"invalid mount config for type…"
"invalid mount config for type…"
"invalid mount config for type…"
"invalid mount config for type…"
```

Comment: Have you tried ` docker -D service ps` ?

Answer (score 4):

Okay so I've been on the right track with that `ps` command. It also has a `--no-trunc` option, so the correct syntax would be the following:

```
$ docker service ps omni_platform_omni_gallery_db --format {{.Error}} --no-trunc
"invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /home/data"
"invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /home/data"
"invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /home/data"
"invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /home/data"
"invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /home/data"
```

Comment: You don't need the --format flag to get the full error, it's just a formatting commands doesn't relate to the question you are asking. But thanks, your question and answer helped me :D